# Travelling to Spain with a Refugee Travel Document issued by the USA

Tags: usa, schengen, spain, refugees, serbian-citizens

I have French Schengen Visa and planning to land in Spain stay few days then continue to France where most of my trip will happen. I'm confused whether I can land in Spain. One consulate said I could, but other said they don't recognize Travel Document from USA. Anyone recently traveled to Spain with RTD? Thanks!

Comment: Does your French visa have any restrictions noted? Related question, which appears to confirm the opinion of the Chicago Spanish Consulate that you cannot enter Spain with a RTD from the USA https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135790/what-countries-in-the-schengen-area-accept-us-travel-document-form-i-571

Comment: Not that I know of. Interesting! Why did LA Consulate say I can travel if I have reentry permit...

Comment: What is your citizenship? You could try checking Timatic https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true Which Consulate did you ask first? And why did you ask two?

Comment: I have Serbian citizenship - which is a Schengen Area and I don't need visa to travel to any European country, but because I need to travel with Travel Document then I need visa. I asked two, cause I read on their website that they can't issue visa for RTD, but read that people went to Spain and they had visa issued from Spain, so I wanted to confirm.

Comment: @Nanina Serbia is not in the Schengen area.  Also, if you get or use a Serbian passport, you might put your refugee status in jeopardy.

Comment: @phoog yeah, my bad. But, Serbians do not need Schengen visa for EU travel. I won't use it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an RTD from any non-EU country, then you will need a visa to seek entry to the Schengen area. You already have that from the French diplomatic mission. Which consulates told you yes and no?

If this is a Visa C with validity in the Schengen States (Etats Schengen) then you should be able to land in Spain and move on to France. The border guard would be well within their rights to question you about your itinerary but if you are honest and show them that the majority of your trip will be in France (flight to France and back home to USA, along with hotel reservation in France with a duration exceeding that of your stay in Spain), then you should have no issues.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Spanish consulate in LA said yes, but Chicago's Spanish consulate said they checked and it's not possible to travel to Spain. If I do - I would be illegally in Spain - that's what they said. I do have Schengen Visa - which technically should be valid in any Schengen area country...

Comment: @Ozzy Are you sure your answer is correct? See the related question I linked to above

Comment: @Traveller digging further into this now, that thread gives some anecdotal evidence. And it's interesting that they added exceptions to that person's visa and not this poster's. Will update

Comment: I have found no text or document within the Spanish consulate websites, Spanish ministry of the Exterior which states which travel documents from the US are not accepted. Does OP have their original passport and is it currently valid? If so they can avoid all of this or simply don't travel to Spain.

Comment: This [document](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/EDIMBURGO/en/Consulado/Documents/Holders%20of%20passports%20who%20do%20not%20require%20and%20who%20require%20a%20visa%20to%20enter%20Spain.doc) states that refugee travel document holders require a visa.

Comment: Yes @MichaelHampton that's correct, RTD holders need visas for most places . And OP has one already, issued by the French diplomatic mission. The question is whether or not Spain will recognize the TRD and allow this person through. If you look at the document you linked, theres an area that says some documents arent recognized by the spanish for entry to their territory.

Comment: @Ozzy If Spain wouldn't recognize the refugee travel document, why do they say holders of the document require a visa?

Comment: @MichaelHampton They recognize RTD's of other countries but apparently not of USA. This is because the US signed the 1967 protocol but not the original 1951 convention which sets out the use of RTD's. So in the Spanish Governments purview, this document is invalid. Meanwhile, places like France DO recognize the document, hence the visa being issued to the OP.

Comment: That's strange, if the Spanish government considers this document invalid, they should stop distributing it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The Spanish government not recognizing it won't stop the US from distributing it because others (probably most countries) do recognize it.

Comment: I think you missed something important here. The document I linked to is on a Spanish government site.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am aware of that, I saw the same document previously. If you look at Refugee Travel Documents there is a (1) next to it. Looking at footnotes you'll find this: *(1) This visa will take at least 4 weeks to process. Included in this category are: Palestinians, Refugees and Stateless Persons. Please note that certain documents are not recognised by the Spanish Authorities and are therefore not valid to travel to Spain. These include Certificates of Identity issued by the Home Office, which are not covered by the Geneva or New York Conventions.*

Comment: @MichaelHampton they specifically mention certain British docs because it is apparently to address UK specific questions.

Comment: Indeed, but we're discussing the USA here, not the UK? Further, not finding anything else useful on the Spanish embassy website, I also checked Timatic, which says the US refugee travel document is OK.

Comment: [https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45978/schengen-visa-in-refugee-travel-document-from-usa?rq=1&fbclid=IwAR0xbXaucvjzdWDnmM9jcRkBaG6zhdQsLS7MHIHIeza57W12GqH1nHTwLj4] - This person says he/she was issued visa from Spanish consulate. I read on another forum that multiple people went to Spain (landed in Spain) and had no issues.

Comment: "This is because the US signed the 1967 protocol but not the original 1951 convention which sets out the use of RTD's": the 1967 protocol incorporates the 1951 convention by reference.